# my Dell machine does not recognize a certain usb driver

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have 2 Dell machines I'm working on (Inspiron 7520, Precision 7730) with Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 installed. 
I have also a USB driver Sandisk 3.0 32G. the drive was working in both of them a few days ago. 
Actually, both the machines do not recognize the driver: `lsusb` does not see the driver at all, no dmesg info about, nothing.
But both the machines regularly works with other USB drivers.

At the same time my Sandisk 3.0 32G works regularly in other different Linux machines, as well in Mac and Win10.
What could be the problem?

Comment: I have Dell machines of different age and kind (no really new one; an old tower and two 'middle-aged' laptops), and they have no problem to see and even boot from USB pendrives. Can you see the problematic USB drive in an UEFI/BIOS menu? If the computer does not see it, the operating system has no chance to see it. If you move the problematic USB drive to another USB port (maybe a USB2 port), will it be seen?

Comment: @sudodus:  I tried to move the problematic USB drive to all the other USB ports of my Dell machines (both of them), but same result. They do not recognize "that" external USB device. But, as well, they recognize every other different USB drive. And the "problematic" device is not corrupted, because I can read it from other laptops (linux,Mac,Win10).